# Is the electromagnetic wave emitted during an atomic electron transition always sinusoidal, and why is there a spectral linewidth?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, wave-particle-duality

I recently engaged in a discussion regarding Planck's relation, which posits that the energy $E$ of a photon is directly proportional to its frequency $f$, symbolized as $E=hf$. The user @Sturrum on a [previous post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/805643/) provided an in-depth answer explaining why this relation holds true particularly for sinusoidal functions in the context of quantum mechanics and the Schrödinger equation.

This explanation, however, led me to ponder the nature of electromagnetic waves emitted by atoms during electron transitions. If Planck's relation is predicated on sinusoidal waveforms, does this imply that photons emitted from atomic electron transitions are always purely sinusoidal? Additionally, how does this reconcile with the fact that in laboratory measurements, we observe a spectral linewidth around the emitted color? This linewidth, while narrow, suggests a range of frequencies rather than a singular sinusoidal frequency. But the truth is that it is centered around a purely sinusoidal frequency, not a triangular or square wave basis frequency. (If not sure about what I mean by this check the linked post).

I am looking to understand:

1. The theoretical basis for the sinusoidal nature of the wave associated with a photon emitted in an electron transition.
2. The practical reasons behind the observed spectral linewidth in laboratory conditions.

Could anyone provide insights or references to elucidate this aspect of quantum emissions?

Comment: it is sinusoidal pulse: it starts and ends, it has rise time and it has a fall time; it can never be a pure sinusoid because it is caused by a *transition*.

Comment: @hyportnex Probably the OP now wonders which frequency from this pulse's band should be used in $hf$.

Comment: @my2cts yes exactly I wonder that now.

Comment: And how can we calculate the real frequencies that compose the sinusoid? Its bandwith, etc @hyportnex

Comment: take the Fourier Transform of the time function (pulse), it contains a finite wide distribution of "pure" sinusoids, not one single frequency but there may be *a* dominant frequency. Which one you call *dominant* is a bit arbitrary and a matter of taste, but the longer the pulse, the more obvious will be the *right* answer.

Comment: @hyportnex I know that, but my question if what mathematical tools/theory do physicists have to predict the exact pulse an electron transition will emit, and on what parameters it depends. Also, why is it centered around a sinusoidal frequency and not a square or triangular one.

Comment: The Fourier transform decomposes a pulse into its *complex* sinusoidal components not triangular or square, or etc. One can decompose a pulse into those non-sinusoidal components, too, but a sinusoid is the eigen-function of any linear time invariant system thus changing the start time at the input changes only the amplitude multiplier of the output. This is why those *other* transforms are most useful in image processing ("wavelet transforms" and some such) but not so much for *time* function processing.

Comment: "@hyportnex, why are electron orbital transitions considered linear time-invariant (LTI)? Additionally, is the emission bandwidth deterministic and always consistent? How is it calculated, and on what variables does it depend?"